# Is is normal there are 3 same requests when Service Workers is enabled?

Tags: service-worker

After enabling Service Worker, I saw 3 same requests in the dev-tool Network tab.

| Name | type | initiator | Size | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxx.com/api/xxxx | xhr | vendor.js | (ServiceWorker) | 500ms |
| xxx.com/api/xxxx | preflight | preflight | 0 B | 250ms |
| xxx.com/api/xxxx | fetch | service-worker.js | 2 kB | 280ms |

Q1.
Is the behavior normal?

Q2.
The first request, the initiator is vendor.js, and size is `(ServiceWorker)`, does that mean the app is requesting from cache?

Q3.
The 3rd one, because this is `network-first` cache strategy, does that mean the Service Worker is requesting the backend to refresh the cache atm?

Q4.
Why does the first one (if it's requesting data from the cache) cost so much time? it's just cache.